# How to have individual x axis ticks labelled according to a pandas dataframe in Bokeh?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have the following dataframe:

```
       Foo  Bar
A      100. 20. 
B      65.2 78.
```

And I want to plot this dataframe is Bokeh, such that I have a line for Foo and a Line for Bar, and the x axis ticks are labelled A and B, and not 0 and 1. So far, I have the following:

```
p = figure()
p.line(df["Foo"], df.index.values)
show(p)
```

But this still shows the x axis ticks as integers and not as the index values A and B as expected. How to show the index values?

I tried the following as well:

```
p = figure(x_range=df.index.values)
p.line(df["Foo"])
show(p)
```

And I still don't see any lines on the graph.

Comment: not sure about Bokeh, but `df.plot()` would do.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part when working with bokeh is that if you want an axis to be categorical, you need to specify it's possible values on the bokeh plot when setting up the figure.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show

df = pd.DataFrame({"Foo":[100, 65.2], "Bar": [20, 78]}, index=["A", "B"])
print(df)
     Foo  Bar
A  100.0   20
B   65.2   78


# Tell bokeh our plot will have a categorical x-axis 
#  whose values are the index of our dataframe
p = figure(x_range=df.index.values, width=250, height=250)
p.line(x="index", y="Foo", source=df, legend_label="Foo")
p.line(x="index", y="Bar", source=df, legend_label="Bar")

p.legend.location = "bottom_right"
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Even while adding the x_range keyword param, and keeping the rest of the code the same, I don't see any lines on the graph.

Comment: In your code you're not specifying anything as the x-values. You're simply giving it the y-values, which would typically plot the line on a linear axis. You need to make sure you specify both the x and y values in your call to `p.line` as I did in my example.